# android gallery no scroll on click

Tags: android

By default it seems, when a gallery item is clicked, the gallery automatically scrolls to center the item that was clicked.  How can I override this behavior?  I do not want the gallery to scroll to center when clicked, I want it to stay where it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a correct solution:

```
    @Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(final MotionEvent e) {     
    boolean handled = super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    onDown(e);

    return handled;
}
```

Comment: I finally retested this. This works great, thank you I had given up on this glad I checked back.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.

First create a class that extends from Gallery and then override the **onSingleTapUp** method:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(final MotionEvent e) {
    final OnItemClickListener listener = getOnItemClickListener();
    final View selectedView = getSelectedView();

    final float tapX = e.getRawX();
    final float tapY = e.getRawY();

    if ((selectedView != null) && (listener != null)
            && (tapX >= selectedView.getLeft()) && (tapX <= selectedView.getRight())
            && (tapY >= selectedView.getTop()) && (tapY <= selectedView.getBottom())) {

        final int selectedPosition = getSelectedItemPosition();

        listener.onItemClick(this, selectedView, selectedPosition, selectedPosition);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used a gallery before (actually i had to watch a youtube view to see it's visual effect first ;-)

So i digged in the source code of gallery and it seems to me that they have tied the selection quite heavy to the positioning, so you would have to override the class and do some heavy code hacking, maybe even reflection, to reach your goal. I can't even tell whether you would succeed.

This is not a solution, but a hint what you should expect if you want to realize that ;-)

Comment: Just getting back to this. from what I can find, what you have stated is correct.  I will have to attempt to copy the gallery source code and implement as my own gallery class.  If anyone has any recommended reading on this topic that would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Gallery has a method to override this.

```
 gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloGallery.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: So what would i need to do within onItemClick to keep the default scroll to center from happening? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this... but you can try the following:

In the `onItemClickListener.onItemClick()`, determine the currently selected position using `Gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()` and then set the position using `Gallery.setSelection(int position)`. I don't know if this will work or not but you can give it a shot.

There is also the `OnItemSelectedListener` which you could try leveraging.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't seem to have the ability to comment on others' posts yet, but for any who found this question but was having issues, note that if you are creating a custom gallery that overrides the `onSingleTap` method (as suggested by Ohgema), you need to override the [constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#Gallery%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29).