# Android: How do you remove the selection behavior from the Gallery?

Tags: android, gallery, selection

I really need horizontal scrolling in my app, so I overrode Gallery and I'm trying to do something with an OnItemSelectedListener, and a GestureDetector I'm calling from an OnTouchListener I've set on the Gallery. What I want is to remove the auto-selection of Gallery items as I scroll, but I want to be able to click an item to select it.

If I set an OnClick listener on a view that is populated in the adapter, the Gallery fails to scroll. Also, the OnItemClicked event is never called for the listener I set for that on the Gallery.

Comment: What do you mean Auto-selection? And also, Do you have images in the gallery or what?

Comment: As you move the gallery left/right it automatically sets the "centered" item to "selected". Gallery is here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove selection from all items you should do this:

```
youGallery.setUnselectedAlpha(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534366/android-gallery-no-scroll-on-click/7534704#7534704) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534366/android-gallery-no-scroll-on-click) will *help* you. It's something which wasn't intended to be ever realized...

Answer (score 0):

For your case why dont you just use a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html). Just put a linear layout inside and add as many imageview's as you need if your using images, or dynamicaly add it in java code.

This will elemenate the selection of gallery by default. This will be easier than trying to Override the Gallery widget default methods.

Comment: I don't know how many views I'm going to put in, because it's data from a server, and is usually pretty large. I need view recycling, so I don't run into memory issues.

Comment: So why cant you do this with horizontalScroolView?

Comment: I didn't want to have to write view recycling code, and it doesn't readily read from an adapter. I'm looking for the easiest solution, but it appears there is none.

Comment: You can add ImageViews into HorizontalScrollView dynamically. Just use scrollView.addView(imageView);

Answer (score -1):

Why not you set some tag while you click on an item in the Gallery to select.
Now once again when you click after the item is selected just check for the tag that you had set, and based on the condition you can move to new screen and whatever task you want to perform.

But keep one thing in mind, you have to set the tag with every gallery item while building the gallery view.

I hope you will get what I want to say.
If still you have any problem then let me know.
I had the same scenario and I solved that.